# System.ObjectDisposedException Error on C# v4.0

Tags: c#, objectdisposedexception

I implemented this code:
[C# Processing Fixed Width Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543223/c-sharp-processing-fixed-width-files)

But since my work PC runs Windows XP I had to save the program using C# v4.0.  Unfortunately the following code:

```
static string filePath = "";

public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void buttonLoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult openFile = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (openFile == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
    }
}

private void buttonProcessFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (filePath == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Load Fixed Width File First", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }
    else
    {
        if (textboxFilePath.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter CSV File Path", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult result = DialogResult.No;

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show("Overwrite CSV File?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);

                var widthList = lines.First().GroupBy(c => c)
                                             .Select(g => g.Count())
                                             .ToList();

                var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

                int startIndex = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < widthList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var pair = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(startIndex, widthList[i]);
                    list.Add(pair);

                    startIndex += widthList[i];
                }

                var csvLines = lines.Select(line => string.Join(",",
                                    list.Select(pair => line.Substring(pair.Key, pair.Value))));

                File.WriteAllLines(textboxFilePath.Text, csvLines);

                MessageBox.Show("File Saved", "Completed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gives me this error when run on Windows XP and compiled in C# v4.0:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot read from a closed TextReader.
   at System.IO.__Error.ReaderClosed()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
   at System.IO.File.<InternalReadLines>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllLines(TextWriter writer, IEnumerable`1 contents)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(String path, IEnumerable`1 contents)
   at FixedWidthFiles.Main.buttonProcessFile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
FixedWidthFiles
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/TEMP/FixedWidthFiles.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The code you showed doesn't seem to match the exception. The exception mentions `Where`. There is no `Where` in your code.

Comment: Could you try another sample file to see?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Updated the post with the exact code I implemented.  Apologies for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx#Y1700) Doc

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use
>   ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient.

Change your code,

```
var widthList = File.ReadLines(@"C:\input.txt").First().GroupBy(c => c)
                             .Select(g => g.Count())
                             .ToList();
```

Or use

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\input.txt");

var widthList = lines.First().GroupBy(c => c)
                             .Select(g => g.Count())
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: What happen if input.txt is very large file?

Comment: Naturally you have to use `ReadLines()` method  but here it is [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535097/bug-in-the-file-readlines-method-of-the-net-framework-4-0)

Comment: That's genius found, just happens on .NET 4, but works well on .NET 4.5

Comment: @AVD - I'm guessing that that is why it won't work for me on Windows XP using .Net 4.0?

Comment: That's true. On my site its working because I've update VS2010 - [service pack1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

Comment: @AVD - I am just installing VS2010 SP1 on my work PC, and will then try your suggestion, so lets see what happens.